# Using other app to send message to line app

Tags: android

I try the following code to send messages to line app. It works; however, before I send message,it will move to the line friends page and I have to choose friends whom I want to send the messages to. How could I modify the code that I could choose friends  at code instead of choosing friends manually.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUEST_ACTION_PICK = 1;
public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "jp.naver.line.android";
public static final String CLASS_NAME = "jp.naver.line.android.activity.selectchat.SelectChatActivity";
private List<ApplicationInfo> m_appList;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendTextHandler(this);
}


public void sendTextHandler(MainActivity view) {
    String sendText = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.send_text)).getText().toString();
    if(checkLineInstalled()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setClassName(PACKAGE_NAME, CLASS_NAME);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sendText);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "LINEがインストールされていません", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
private boolean checkLineInstalled(){
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    m_appList = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    boolean lineInstallFlag = false;
    for (ApplicationInfo ai : m_appList) {
        if(ai.packageName.equals(PACKAGE_NAME)){
            lineInstallFlag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return lineInstallFlag;
}

}
```

The code is from https://gist.github.com/ekos/3993270.

Comment: The issue here is y u want to define the name of friends in the code itself. I mean it is not mandatory that user will send message to same person all time. He/she sends msg A to person X and msg B to person Y. So if u fix in code that msg will go to person X then the app becomes less useful. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right but I have to let users choose friends whom they want send messages to at the first time that they use the app and when something happened, it will trigger my app to send messages. It's too inconvenient for user to choose friends whom they want send messages to every time.

Comment: Okay so u want user to select people at beginning of session. What I have experienced with another chat application, it is rarely possible. But for LINE u should go through the documentation. U will first need to get list of friends of logged user, show it in ur app once and when user select the name save them. Pass these names in the intent to LINE app (but for this u need to see if the LINE intent has some provision for this or not)

Comment: Yes,and this is what I concern. I am not sure that the LINE app has released the relative API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to open a specific user based on the ID you can do the following:

```
String userId = findUserId();
String sendText = "line://ti/p/~" + userId;
Intent intent = null;
try {
    intent = Intent.parseUri(sendText, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to make a message and then be able to choose who to send it to you can use the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("line://msg/text/" + getMessage()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hello, i have a problem with this.
Line app will crash if user do not login
Could you help  ?

Comment: Which part was crashing? Was it the "line://msg/text/" or was it "line://ti/p/~"

Comment: how to find a userid of imo user ?